How to set key(tab key) to nothing using Autohotkey
Basically my tab key for some reason keeps spamming, I went to a repair shop and they couldn't figure it out. We tried removing the key to try to fix the problem to check if maybe a crumb got left or something. I used to have the same problem with the k key. Now neither key works when I press them, they have mind of their own.
So my idea is to set these keys to nothing so that it stops interfering with my work flow.
I tried setting them to a useless key but the problem is that everytime it spams, I cant move my mouse.

A new keyboard, maybe?

I'm afraid that this is not possible, I already tried that and it didn't work, I just need to set the tab key to nothing. @Guillius

I'm afraid I don't understand how a completely new keyboard (all keys, not just one or two keys) does not work as a solution? If that's the case then maybe your problem with tab or other keys comes from a software, and not a hardware issue?

or is this a laptop and not an external keyboard?

That would be correct on both, yes it is a software issue as we replaced the keyboard entirely and was still met with the problem. Yes it is a laptop keyboard, not an external keyboard. @Guillius

I do not understand who in their right mind would say this question needs to be on another branch of Stack Exchange. There, they would say ❝ Closed. This question is not about (blah blah blah).❞ Seriously, just a few lines regarding ”going to a keyboard shop“ and ”checking for crumbs jammed inside the keyboard“ and it's suddenly off-topic?! How? I vote on the asker's behalf that this question needs to be reopened.

Alright, I figured it out, how to replace the tab key with nothing, in you're .ahk file, simply type one line: Tab::return.
Then you can remap the tab key to something else like you're right alt using another .ahk file, add this line in that file: RAlt::Tab.

Quick correction:- You don't need another .ahk file to put the RAlt::Tab line in.
